# Need advice on file/directory enumeration code

Tags: c#, file-system

In various projects I need to enumerate all files and folders from a specific root folder, either on a local drive or across a network.  I've broken the task down into two `IEnumerable` implementations as follows:

```
static IEnumerable<string> EnumeratePaths(string root)
{
    if (root == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("root");
    if (!Directory.Exists(root))
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid root path", "root");

    if (root.Length > 3)
        root = Path.GetDirectoryName(root + "\\");

    Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
    queue.Enqueue(root);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        string curr = queue.Dequeue();
        bool failed = false;
        try
        {
            foreach (var path in Directory.GetDirectories(curr))
                queue.Enqeue(path);
        }
        catch
        {
            failed = true;
        }
        if (!failed)
            yield return curr;
    }
}

static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string root)
{
    var paths = EnumeratePaths(root);
    foreach (var nxt in paths)
    {
        foreach (var filename in Directory.GetFiles(nxt))
            yield return filename;
    }
}
```

From these I can build LINQ expressions to do filtering, etc.  When I'm scanning a folder structure containing a few million files in several thousand folders this saves me from filling up memory with data that I only need once.

However in certain cases I have to process folders that contain tens of thousands of files, and the entire process stalls at the call to `GetDirectories` or `GetFiles` while it processes the folder... and bulks up my process memory significantly with the resultant arrays.  Worse, this happens twice in `EnumerateFiles` - once when `EnumeratePaths` calls `GetDirectories`, then again when I call `GetFiles`.

So my questions are:

1. Is there anything overtly inefficient in the implementation as it stands (not related to the file system problems mentioned).
2. How can I best reduce the memory bloat and so on when processing folders containing huge numbers of files?

---

Update 1: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

As MarcinJuraszek pointed out there is already a way to do full-depth file enumeration using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` that doesn't require me to fetch a full array of results in one hit.  That's good because one of the folders I'm scanning has 150,000+ files in it (don't ask).

Here's some code I wrote to test it, using a drive mapped to a network share:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sw.Restart();
    var enumfiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("I:\\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    int maxlen = enumfiles.Max(fname => fname.Length);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:0.00}s", i, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
}
```

The average time over 10 runs was 73.942 seconds.  Substituting the `EnumerateFiles` method above gave an average of 72.264 seconds - close enough that network traffic variations could account for the difference.  As for memory usage... `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` gives a peak working set (from `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PeakWorkingSet64`) of `35,896,786` bytes after 10 runs, compared to `80,711,680` bytes - a significant improvement.

Still feels like there is a lot of room for improvement though.

---

Update 2: `FindFirstFile()` API

After much googling and testing I managed to get the kernel32 `FindFirstFile()` API working in C#, hoping that it would provide a bit more of a boost.  For a few of my projects it might do, since it gives me all sorts of useful information in the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure during enumeration... but the overall performance when just enumerating file name is approximately equivalent to `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, both in time and memory usage.

Thanks Marcin - answer accepted.

---

Update 3: `FindFirstFile` revisited

Final update.  Using some of the code from [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.findfirstfile) I've rewritten my FindFile enumeration code as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA finddata;
    Queue<string> paths = new Queue<string>();
    paths.Enqueue(path);

    while (paths.Count > 0)
    {
        var nxtpath = paths.Dequeue();

        using (var fh = FindFirstFile(Path.Combine(nxtpath, "*"), out finddata))
        {
            if (fh.IsInvalid)
                continue;
            bool ok = true;
            while (ok)
            {
                if ((finddata.dwFileAttributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
                {
                    if (finddata.cFileName != "." && finddata.cFileName != "..")
                        paths.Enqueue(Path.Combine(nxtpath, finddata.cFileName));
                }
                else
                    yield return Path.Combine(nxtpath, finddata.cFileName);

                ok = FindNextFile(fh, out finddata);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This performs almost twice as fast as `Directory.EnumerateFiles` in my test case - network mapped drive containing numerous files and folders including one folder with over 150,000 files.  I think this one is going to end up in my library :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods? There is an overload which takes `SearchOption` enum and lets you query subdirectiries too.

```
static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string root)
{
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}

static IEnumerable<string> EnumeratePaths(string root)
{
    return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
```

You can see, that `GetDirectories` and `GetFiles` uses the same logic as `Enumerate*` methods, just instantiate a list, instead of returning one element at the time.